# Cannot find module '@/components/HelloWorld.vue' or its corresponding type declarations.Vetur(2307)

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I have a fresh project which I created using the vue command line tool. vue create . But when I type npm serve, the component import is highlighted as red. This is a fresh creation of the project, I haven't changed anything.

Cannot find module '@/components/HelloWorld.vue' or its corresponding type declarations.Vetur(2307).

Comment: It sounds like you're using Typescript but your `tsconfig.json` is not configured properly. What you posted is not enough to repro as the command line tool's output can vary greatly depending on what settings you choose during the installation process. If you need help, consider creating a *runnable* [mcve] on codesandbox.io (or similar), making sure it reproduces the bug. At the very least, you should show the contents of `tsconfig.json` and `package.json`. It would also be useful to know if your project uses `vite` or `@vue/cli` (it's probably `@vue/cli` but you should make that clear).

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The error message indicates you're using Vetur, which is likely the cause of the problem.

From [Vue docs](https://vuejs.org/guide/typescript/overview.html#ide-support):

> ℹ️ TIP
>
> Volar replaces [Vetur](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=octref.vetur), our previous official VSCode extension for Vue 2. If you have Vetur currently installed, make sure to disable it in Vue 3 projects.

This also applies to Vue 2 projects. Disabling Vetur and enabling [Volar](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=johnsoncodehk.volar) should resolve the issue.

Comment: But what if you're already using Volar?

Comment: @Maritim Need more context to troubleshoot. It could be that the actual file doesn't exist at that path, or that your path aliases are not configured properly. I suggest posting a new question so that someone familiar with the topic can provide you with an answer. I'll chime in if I can.

Answer (score 0):

If you using Vue 3 , it's better to use [Volar](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vue.volar) extenstion.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31870506)